# Subrings/subalgebras of $\mathbb Z[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Is there any complete classification of the subrings/subalgebras of $\mathbb Z[x]$? I tried searching Google and Google Scholar but couldn't find anything.  If there doesn't exist such a classification, is there a reason why not?

Comment: I suspect that subrings of $\Bbb Z[X]$ can get quite complicated.

Comment: It depends on  whether you want a description up to isomorphism or not.

Comment: I reckon that $R=\Bbb Z+2\Bbb Z[X]$ is a non-Noetherian subring of $\Bbb Z[X]$. Once one has non-Noetherianness things get complicated.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Indeed, the ideals $(2x, 2x^2, \dots, 2x^n)$ form an increasing chain which never stabilizes (since, for all $n \geq 1$, $2x^{n+1} \notin (2x, \dots, 2x^n)$).